# swift iphone setting for 24-Hour Time is disabled results in error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

So the app was working just fine, until I disable in Settings-> General-> Date&Time the 24-Hour Time setting. Now I get an error where I use the date for the first time:

> let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
>   dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
>   dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
>   let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateGame)
>   print(date!)

Is there a proper way to work with the date in this case?
Or a general way to work with the date that works in both cases(24-Hour Time setting enabled and disabled)?

Comment: Can you post the string you are parsing?

Comment: @rckoenes sure: 2016-08-12T18:00:00+0000

Answer (score 5):

I know its an old question, but I'll leave here the answer for future references ;)

You need to set the Locale to en_US_POSIX to avoid error in case the 24hs is disabled on the user's phone.

`dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")`